# Unshifted array elements not shown in *ngFor in angular5

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular5

I am trying to Listing all countries that from a JSON response in a `ngFor`, Also tried to move `US` and `Canada` to the top of the list using `unshift`.

Here is the code

```
let newData = this.countries.filter(item => item.CountryCode!=='CA');
newData.unshift({idCity:39,countryName:'Canada',countryCode:'CA'});
newData = newData.filter(item => item.CountryCode!=='US');
newData.unshift({idCity:231,countryName:'United States',countryCode:'US'});
this.countries = newData;
console.log(this.countries);
```

I am getting the proper result in `console.log(this.countries);` But the unshifted objects not showing in the ngFor

```
<div class="drop_option col-xs-12" *ngFor="let countries of countries; let i = index" (click)="fetchCountries(i,$event)">{{countries.CountryName}}</div>
```

Comment: It's just a typo, `newData.unshift({idCity:39,countryName:'Canada',countryCode:'CA'});` here change `countryName` to `CountryName`, use a interface/class and strongly type your methods/variables to avoid such errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a typo.

```
newData.unshift({idCity:39,countryName:'Canada',countryCode:'CA'});
<div class="drop_option col-xs-12" *ngFor="let countries of countries; let i = index" (click)="fetchCountries(i,$event)">{{countries.CountryName}}</div>
```

Notice that you have used property `countryName` while performing `unshift` and `CountryName` in the template.

Please take advantage of typescript to identify such errors quickly

Create an interface/class

```
export interface CountryItem {
  idCity: number;
  CountryCode: string;
  CountryName: string;
}
```

and strongly type your variables

```
public countries: CountryItem[];
```

By doing this, errors such as these can be identified by the IDE's linter saving you time.

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1v8zea)